# How to do serial communication using vb.net language

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, .net

I'm making project of automated polling system using SMS. How can i read the text message in the cellphone and display it in textbox?

Comment: This question is about to be closed as "not a real question", meaning that you haven't provided sufficient details about your problem and what you ultimately want to achieve for people to be able to answer it. For future reference, you might want to read some [tips on how to ask a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: sorry sir but im only a begginer

Comment: It's no problem. Beginners are just as welcome here as everyone else! But for people to be able to help you as much as possible, you should try and start including more detail in your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the classes in the [System.IO.Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) namespace, namely [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).
There is even an (albeit brief) example available in the Microsoft KB that illustrates how to send AT commands to a connected modem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x7cdt5c.aspx

Comment: +1, mainly for bothering to answer a question where the asker couldn't be bothered to provide sufficient info.

Comment: thank you sir i have another question how can i display the text message that i receives from the cellphone

Comment: @Jiggy Degamo System.Console.WriteLine( textmsg );

Comment: sir can i have a simple syntax on how to display the text message in the textboxes